# Watch changes in component variable Angular 5

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular5

In AngularJS it was possible to `$watch` a variable in a controller, and this trigger was activated if the variable was changed from anywhere (from template when ng-model changed or programmatically, from controller).

I'd like to know if it's possible to accomplish the same functionality in Angular 5.

I must be able to change my variable directly from my template, without calling any functions, like this:

```
<button class="btn-link bc-2th" (click)="persistentComponentConfig.searchFiltersVisible = !persistentComponentConfig.searchFiltersVisible">
  FILTERS
</button>
```

But also I have to change it programmatically:

```
updateVariable () {
  this.persistentComponentConfig.searchFiltersVisible = !this.persistentComponentConfig.searchFiltersVisible
}
```

In both cases (there are many, actually), I have to trigger another function after the model changes.

I was able to do it by creating a reactive form and subscribing to it's 'valueChanges' property, but I don't need an entire form controller, I just need some properties to be stored in a component object to control some template *ngIf/hide/show directives and dispatch the changes to my `ngrx` store.

I tried to create it using Observables and BehaviorSubjects, but more boilerplate was needed to propagate all changes to my store through 'next()'. I'm just looking for something identical to AngularJS's `$watch` functionality.

How could I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: How/when is the variable changed? How about posting some example code?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for yout reply. The variable is changed directly from my template or by a private component function. I've updated the question with a piece of my code.

Comment: No offense, but it seems you were abusing $watch, and want to keep using this bad practice in Angular. If something needs to be done when the variable changes, then simply encapsulate the change into a function, and call that function instead of mutating the field directly. It's all about OO design.

Comment: Yes, I know this is a bad pratice, and I totally used to avoid this in AngularJS. But in my current project I'm creating a functionality that keeps my application current state in sync with localStorage using this library: ngrx-store-localstorage. So I don't need only dynamic templates with structural directives, I need to propagate those changes to my store and save them to localStorage, so when the user refreshes the page, the latest layout configs is kept, like collapsed menus, visible elements, etc.

Comment: Your suggestion of encapsulating the changes in functions totally works, but I was looking for a way to do it automatically only by detecting changes in my component config object, without having to call functions on every single mutation and keeping my templates cleaner. My config object has almost 50 different properties, and some of them are 4 levels deep nested, and this is going to be really annoying to handle by encapsulating the changes in functions and triggering them manually. There's no way to achieve this in Angular? Maybe with Observables? Thanks again for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges), especially `OnChanges`.

It gets called, whenever at least one data property changes its value. It gets called with a `SimpleChanges` object, which includes the changed properties and their values.

From the docs:

```js
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  for (let propName in changes) {
    let chng = changes[propName];
    let cur  = JSON.stringify(chng.currentValue);
    let prev = JSON.stringify(chng.previousValue);
    this.changeLog.push(`${propName}: currentValue = ${cur}, previousValue = ${prev}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The thing is that my variable is not assigned to any @Input or ngModel, it's a button function that changes it, so the ngOnChanges won't trigger...

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `get` and `set` functions of a variable inside your component. Your trigger should be defined inside the `set` function.

This way:

```
  _searchFiltersVisible = null

  get searchFiltersVisible() : string {
    return this._searchFiltersVisible
  }

  set searchFiltersVisible(v: string) {

    // trigger any action you want
    // call another function, emit an event etc
    this.anyEvent.emit(v)

    this._searchFiltersVisible = v
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing identical to using `$watch`.

One common method is using getter's and setter's on a class that emit the data changes. You will have to manually subscribe to each.